# circular dependency Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome-devtools, ngrx

I've uploaded the whole project in [enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqcbvy)

after many attempts of I got this error each time I run the same code and get these errors:

> `ERROR in node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/actions.d.ts(18,21):
> error TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
>
> node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/actions.d.ts(22,21): error
> TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
>
> node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/actions.d.ts(26,21): error
> TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
>
> node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/actions.d.ts(31,21): error
> TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
>
> node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/actions.d.ts(36,21): error
> TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
>
> node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/actions.d.ts(40,21): error
> TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
>
> node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/actions.d.ts(44,21): error
> TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
>
> node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/actions.d.ts(51,21): error
> TS1039: Initializers are not allowed
> node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/actions.d.ts(56,21): error
> TS1039: Initializers are not allowed
>
> node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/actions.d.ts(61,21): error
> TS1039: Initializers are not allowed
>
> node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/actions.d.ts(66,21): error
> TS1039: Initializers are not allowed
>
> node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/actions.d.ts(71,21): error
> TS1039: Initializers are not allowed
>
> node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/actions.d.ts(76,21): error
> TS1039: Initializers are not allowed
>
> i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile. `

[image]

with some chance without changing anything in code the project compiles successfully but with another error which is `Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for CoinEffects: (?, [object Object]).`

after many searches I discovered that it's about circular dependency it tried to fixed but in vain is it about dependencies or something else?

Comment: It looks like there's an error in a module's source code that's a dependency of your project. This is on the developers of `@ngrx/store-devtools` not anything you did. Either upgrade to a later version of `@ngrx/store-devtools` or use a different version of TypeScript compiler that allows that language construct without throwing an error.

Comment: thank you @amphetamachine the first error disappears it's all about versions I changed the version of store-devtools and et goes well .. but the second one stills `Can't resolve all parameters for CoinEffects: (?, [object Object])`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Thank u i discovered that it s all about packages nothing wrong in code .

Comment: Usually if a module depends on a specific version of TypeScript, it should declare it in its own `package.json` file. That way, package managers can look at it and decide which version to use so it can be compatible with all your dependencies. It doesn't always happen.

Answer (score 7):

You need to set the same version for packages `@ngrx/store` and `@ngrx/store-devtools` in `package.json`.